# Paypal Server API. No money transfered

Tags: java, json, api, paypal

I'm integrating paypal in our shopping system.

I'm using the Java Api.

In the current form the process is the following:

1. The user chooses paypal as payment and clicks on "Pay Order"
2. The Server sends a an createOrder Request with Capture Intent.
3. The Server receives a response with links.
4. The user is redirected to the "approve" link.
5. After finishing paypal redirects the user to the shop page with the "thanks for your order message".

All this is working as expected.

But no payment is done / no money transfered.

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance!

For reference the request/response:

```
Request: {}, {
             "application_context" : {
                 "user_action" : "PAY_NOW",
                     "landing_page" : "BILLING",
                     "return_url" : "https://www.foobar.de.localhost:8443/payment/paypal?result=ok&order_id=MGS063464&secret=2E1C1B304178...",
                     "brand_name" : "<removed>",
                     "cancel_url" : "https://www.foobar.de.localhost:8443/payment/paypal?result=cancel&order_id=MGS063464",
                     "shipping_preference" : "SET_PROVIDED_ADDRESS"
             },
                 "purchase_units" : [ {
                     "amount" : {
                         "breakdown" : {
                             "shipping" : {
                                 "value" : "3",
                                 "currency_code" : "EUR"
                             },
                             "item_total" : {
                                 "value" : "2.45",
                                 "currency_code" : "EUR"
                             }
                         },
                         "value" : "5.45",
                         "currency_code" : "EUR"
                     },
                     "reference_id" : "MGS063464",
                     "shipping" : {
                         "address" : {
                             "country_code" : "DE",
                             "address_line_1" : "<removed>",
                             "admin_area_2" : "<removed>",
                             "postal_code" : "<removed>"
                         },
                         "name" : {
                             "full_name" : "<removed>"
                         }
                     },
                     "description" : "<removed>,
                     "items" : [ {
                         "quantity" : "1",
                         "name" : "<removed>",
                         "unit_amount" : {
                             "value" : "2.45",
                             "currency_code" : "EUR"
                         },
                         "sku" : "OCI08"
                     } ]
                 } ],
                 "intent" : "CAPTURE"
         }
```

```
Response: {}, {
              "create_time" : "2021-03-14T10:52:46Z",
                  "purchase_units" : [ {
                      "payee" : {
                          "email_address" : "<removed>",
                          "merchant_id" : "L4EC8HB5DTVSC"
                      },
                      "amount" : {
                          "breakdown" : {
                              "shipping" : {
                                  "value" : "3.00",
                                  "currency_code" : "EUR"
                              },
                              "item_total" : {
                                  "value" : "2.45",
                                  "currency_code" : "EUR"
                              }
                          },
                          "value" : "5.45",
                          "currency_code" : "EUR"
                      },
                      "reference_id" : "MGS063464",
                      "shipping" : {
                          "address" : {
                              "country_code" : "DE",
                              "address_line_1" : "<removed>",
                              "admin_area_2" : "<removed>",
                              "postal_code" : "<removed>"
                          },
                          "name" : {
                              "full_name" : "<removed>"
                          }
                      },
                      "description" : "<removed>",
                      "items" : [ {
                          "quantity" : "1",
                          "name" : "<removed>",
                          "unit_amount" : {
                              "value" : "2.45",
                              "currency_code" : "EUR"
                          },
                          "sku" : "OCI08"
                      } ]
                  } ],
                  "links" : [ {
                      "method" : "GET",
                      "rel" : "self",
                      "href" : "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders/5MY66978KX626104P"
                  }, {
                      "method" : "GET",
                      "rel" : "approve",
                      "href" : "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/checkoutnow?token=5MY66978KX626104P"
                  }, {
                      "method" : "PATCH",
                      "rel" : "update",
                      "href" : "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders/5MY66978KX626104P"
                  }, {
                      "method" : "POST",
                      "rel" : "capture",
                      "href" : "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders/5MY66978KX626104P/capture"
                  } ],
                  "id" : "5MY66978KX626104P",
                  "intent" : "CAPTURE",
                  "status" : "CREATED"
          }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing an API call, step 5 should instead be: The Server sends a Capture Order request.

Your final Step 6 should be to thank the buyer only if the capture was successful

See 'Capture Order' in [the documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/server-side-api-calls/#server-side-api-calls).

---

Redirecting to an "approve" link is an old integration method, for old websites. For a modern user experience you should keep your page loaded (not redirect away) by changing your 'Create Order' and 'Capture Order' to be two server routes that return only JSON data (no other HTML or text)

Pair those routes with the following approval flow: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

Comment: Thanks a lot. I wish there where some order-flow / request diagram in this *** documentation.